# How to include a parent Spring project (using Git submodule)?

Tags: git, spring, maven-2, build-process, ivy

I'm currently developing multiple web applications using Spring. I'm using Maven for building and Git for version control. At the moment I'm trying to find a way to split development of some things used by all webapps, e.g. I have some helper classes that are the same for all projects. The problem is, I don't want to use only classes, but also resource files and some sort of parent POM while still being independent from a repository and able to benefit from Git.

Although I'm not enthusiastic to change the build system, I'm not a real fan of Maven. Especially the concept of inheritance and aggregation is what constrains me right now. Maybe Ivy is an option?

I'd want to give you a quick overview of my setup:

There's some sort of parent project including some classes, Spring configuration files and other resources like templates, images and style sheets. Let's call it `base`. This one is not a complete Spring webapp and won't be deployed. There are several other projects which *inherit* from `base` and should be packed into a WAR. Let's call them `webapp1` and `webapp2`.

`base`, `webapp1` and `webapp2` have their own Git repositories:

```
\
 |
 |- base.git       (base's repository)
 |
 |- webapp1.git    (webapp1's repository)
 | \
 |   base          (base used as a Git submodule)
 |
 |- webapp2.git    (webapp2's repository)
   \
     base          (base used as a Git submodule)
```

I want to be able to change `base`s code from inside the the webapps using a Git submodule and also be able to build a fully functional WAR of each webapp using `mvn package` inside the webapp`s directory.

Maven's `parent` or `module` don't allow a dynamic approach like this. I didn't find a way to use `module` like that at all and using `parent` for my needs is complex and static: Every change to `base` would require a new version to be pushed to the repository so that the webapp`s can inherit from it.

Maybe I didn't completely understand Maven's inheritance, but I'm pretty lost right now.

Did anyone achieve something similar with success? What build system did you use and how?

Comment: is base just a simple JAR that needs to be packaged into the WAR files?

Comment: No it isn't. Like mentioned above, I also want to include some sort of "meta build configuration". What could be achieved with a parent POM. There are some tasks that have to be executed for all projects and I don't want to copy and paste them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution by myself.

The basic solution of my problem is a small sub-element of the `<parent>` element called `<relativePath>`. It allows to search for the parent POM in the specified directory. Otherwise you would always need to deploy a new version before you could test it within your application.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>base</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0</groupId>
    <relativePath>base</relativePath>
</parent>
```

But that was only the starting point, allowing to work with a Git submodule. To get it really working, I needed to do the following:

- Create a WAR with classes and resources from both, the webapp and `base`, i.e. all files inside

  ```
  base/src/main/java
  base/src/main/resources
  base/src/main/webapp
  src/main/java
  src/main/resources
  src/main/webapp
  ```

  While resources are pretty easy to cover, a bit of configuration for `org.apache.maven.plugin:maven-war-plugin` is needed to get the webapp resources into the WAR. Compiling of two different source folders requires a plugin, so I need to use `org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin` to get the classes of `base` into the WAR.
- Additionally, I used a lot of filtering for the resources, so there's almost no need for customization of the basic files to get a webapp up and running. For example I use `${project.artifactId}` inside my main template file, so my HTML `<head>` will look something like this for a webapp called `webapp1`:

  ```
  <link href="stylesheets/base.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
  <link href="stylesheets/webapp1.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" />
  ```

It really took a lot of trial and error, but at last I got it working and I think this is the best way to achieve my target using Maven. This would've been a lot easier using a dynamic tool like [Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org), but sadly Buildr is slow on Windows (thanks to Ruby) and doesn't integrate very well into most IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case seems to be a good use case for [overlays](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) (also have a look at [the examples](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/war-overlay.html)).

> Overlays are used to share common resources accross multiple web applications. In general, all dependencies of a WAR project are collected in WEB-INF/lib except for WAR artifacts that are overlayed on the WAR source.

But *base* wouldn't be "under" the webapp module, it would very likely be a sibling module  (maybe it can be "in" the webapp using some Git black magic but this goes beyond my Git skills and I fail at thinking of how this could be handled with Maven). No, really, I think the Maven way would be to use overlays. And if this is not what you want, better use something else than Maven IMO.

Comment: This seems like a better approach than what I wrapped up with a Maven inheritance using `parent`. But it lacks, well, the inheritance. Combining both would result in a similar bloated configuration without dynamics and support for a smart Git workflow.

Seems like Maven isn't playing that well with Git (and especially Git submodules). I'm already investigating alternatives and, like said before, I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: @Koraktor Maven is playing well with Maven, you have to follow its rules. What you want to do is not possible with Maven: you can't inherit from a project that has not a `pom` packaging (I don't see why you need inheritance between webappX and base BTW). You need something entirely configurable here i.e. Ant+Maven Ant tasks or Ant+Ivy (you don't want to compile "base" twice I guess, you need custom build logic). But honestly, I see more what you loose than what you win with your "smart Git workflow".