# create an common module among 2 spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, git-submodules

I am using spring boot. There are some common classes to the 2 exsisting spring boot projects. I need to add common module as sub module to them .how to do this please guide me step by step.

Comment: You can create a separate project for same with the common classes and after that, you can import that jar into your actual project to use the functionalities.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2333508/6309 could help

Comment: should i create another spring boot project as sub module?but i need only few java files to sore it.how to generate sub module?and maintain it as seperate bitbucked project?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a library/jar/dependency of the common code and than you can access it from the dependent client.

A very detailed example is provided in the below article

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/06/13/code-reuse-in-microservices-architecture.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Maven project/Gradle of common code project and add dependency as Maven or Gradle modules to the project that you are using,so now you can access it from the common project.
you will have projects like this below, where your common module will be shared amongst the project e.g. constants. or messages.

[image]

You can also go with parent-child project structure if your requirement is too complex. 
here is link is for your reference [link](https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/maven-parent-child-pom-example/).